# How to set limits on each individual Int

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to change a list of `Int`s in Haskell to make keep them within specific limits, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to make every int in the list sit between 32 and 127 but it's not working, could anyone explain why this isn't working?

```
limit :: Int -> Int
limit n | n > 127  = n `mod` 127 + 32
        | n < 32 = n  + 127 - 32
        | otherwise = n

limitList :: [Int] -> [Int]
limitList [] = []
limitList (x:xs) = [limit x] ++ limitList xs
```

Comment: What do you mean with"sit between 127 and 32". What should happen if it is *not between* these bounds?

Comment: Let n=253, and observe that your first clause doesn't appear to do what you want. There are similar problems with the second clause. Why are you adding 32?

Comment: If it's not between these bounds I want it to loop back around, so if the int is 128 I want it to be 32 and if the int is 31 i want it to be 127.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong.  The mod should be by the width of the window, not the maximum value.   ``result = input `mod` window + minimum where window = maximum - mimimum``

Comment: (Meta suggestion: in future questions, don't say just "it's not working". Tell us what you expect to happen, and how your results fail to match that, from the start.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to transform `Int`s that are *not* in the 32-127 range by applying a modulo transformation. Therefore we can first implement a `helper` function:

```
helper x = 32 + mod (x-32) (128-32)
```

This results in:

```
Prelude> helper 31
127
Prelude> helper 32
32
Prelude> helper 127
127
Prelude> helper 128
32
```

Next our function `limitList` is only a `map`ping with that helper:

```
limitList = map helper
    where helper x = 32 + mod (x-32) (128-32)
```

This generates:

```
Prelude> limitList [1,4..256]
[97,100,103,106,109,112,115,118,121,124,127,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,100,103,106,109,112,115,118,121,124,127,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,100,103,106,109,112,115,118,121,124,127,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64]
```